# Keycloak configuration for spring boot in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, keycloak

I have given all the roles,permissions,resources and policies in key cloak console.But why do I have to give roles and resources again in application.properties.If i don't give those in application.properties,all the resources are accessible.So,what actually do i have to mention in application.properties.

[evaluation in keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6vp.png)

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJvct.png)

[permissions for resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwzaa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have used a lower version of spring boot.You must have spring boot 2.0 or above for integrating with keycloak.